# Set the thumb sign of the Slider as per value selection in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have used RangeSlider from slider.i have used library"**rn-range-slider**".

i have used this for filtering my data.

**Description of image:--**

if i visit this screen first the slider min max range(from 0 to maximum value) set as per data range.if i am change some value from slider the data is showing accordingly.if again i am going to click the filter icon the slider  set to selected value(from selected min to selected maximum value).
[image]

In this image,i already filtered my data from 340798 to maximum value.if you can notice the thumb did not take place of that much range.the thumb sign also set from beginning.

RangeSlider.js:--

```
const AmountSlider = (props) => {
  const [low, setLow] = useState(low);
  const [high, setHigh] = useState(high);
  const [min, setMin] = useState(Number(props.min));
  const [max, setMax] = useState(Number(props.max));
const handleRangeChange = useCallback(
    (lowValue, highValue) => {
      setLow(lowValue);
      setHigh(highValue);
      props.highValue(highValue);

      props.lowValue(lowValue);
    },
    [setLow, setHigh]
  );
  return (
    <View>
      <RangeSlider
        style={styles.slider}
        min={min}
        max={max}
        step={1}
        initialLowValue={low}
        floatingLabel
        renderThumb={renderThumb}
        renderRail={renderRail}
        renderRailSelected={renderRailSelected}
        renderLabel={renderLabel}
        renderNotch={renderNotch}
        onValueChanged={handleRangeChange}
      />
```

Parent-class:--

```
const sortedData = async () => {
    //NOTE: set min max value to default
    filterSalaryDataByYear(arrayYearInt[yearIndex]);
    const newData = allDataPerYear.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.NETO_TASHLUM >= Number(minValue) &&
        item.NETO_TASHLUM <= Number(maxValue)
    );
    setMinValue(minValue);
    setAllDataFiltered(newData);
    setFilterColorChange(true);
    refRBSheet.current.close();
  };
<AmountSlider
              min={minValue}
              max={maxValue}
              lowValue={lowerValue}
              highValue={higherValue}
              minValue={minValue}
              onChange={setValue}
            />
            <CustomFlatButton
              buttonLabel={"סינון"}
              functionToCall={sortedData}
            />
```

i want to set the thumb sign also indicate what i am selecting like below one not from beginning and also same for maximum value.
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you pass a low and high value to your slider ? right now you don't pass current values

Comment: i am passing min and max value to slider.if i am passing low and high value i am getting error :--`Invariant Violation: [9253,"RCTView",{"transform":[{"translateX":"<<NaN>>"}]}] is not usable as a native method argument`

Comment: I guess I have been there before, is it possible to provide an expo demo of this problem?
https://snack.expo.dev/